# php shell_exec returns different results compared to terminal

Tags: php, apache2, shell

I try to run `shell_exec("ls -l /dev");` to list all entries in `/dev` and I get this list:

```
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  180 Oct 10 11:19 char
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   11 Oct 10 11:19 core -> /proc/kcore
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   13 Oct 10 11:19 fd -> /proc/self/fd
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 1, 7 Oct 10 11:19 full
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    0 Oct  8 14:21 hugepages
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   28 Oct 10 11:19 log -> /run/systemd/journal/dev-log
drwxrwxrwt 2 root root   40 Oct  8 14:21 mqueue
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 1, 3 Oct 10 11:19 null
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 5, 2 Oct 10 11:19 ptmx
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    0 Oct  8 14:21 pts
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 1, 8 Oct 10 11:19 random
drwxrwxrwt 2 root root   40 Oct 10 11:38 shm
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 Oct 10 11:19 stderr -> /proc/self/fd/2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 Oct 10 11:19 stdin -> /proc/self/fd/0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 Oct 10 11:19 stdout -> /proc/self/fd/1
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 5, 0 Oct 10 11:19 tty
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 1, 9 Oct 10 11:19 urandom
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 1, 5 Oct 10 11:19 zero
```

if I run ls -l /dev in terminal I get this:

```
total 0
crw-r--r-- 1 root root       10, 235 Oct  8 14:21 autofs
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root           200 Oct  8 14:21 block
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root            80 Oct  8 14:21 bsg
crw------- 1 root root       10, 234 Oct  8 14:21 btrfs-control
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root            60 Oct  8 14:21 bus
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root          3660 Oct  9 01:59 char
crw------- 1 root root        5,   1 Oct  8 14:21 console
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root            11 Oct  8 14:21 core -> /proc/kcore
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root            60 Oct  8 14:21 cpu
crw------- 1 root root       10,  60 Oct  8 14:21 cpu_dma_latency
crw------- 1 root root       10, 203 Oct  8 14:21 cuse
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root           160 Oct  8 14:21 disk
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root            60 Oct  8 14:21 dma_heap
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root           100 Oct  8 14:21 dri
crw-rw---- 1 root video      29,   0 Oct  8 14:21 fb0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root            13 Oct  8 14:21 fd -> /proc/self/fd
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root        1,   7 Oct  8 14:21 full
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root       10, 229 Oct  8 14:21 fuse
crw------- 1 root root      239,   0 Oct  8 14:21 hidraw0
crw------- 1 root root      239,   1 Oct  8 14:21 hidraw1
crw------- 1 root root      239,   2 Oct  8 14:21 hidraw2
crw------- 1 root root      239,   3 Oct  8 14:21 hidraw3
crw------- 1 root root       10, 228 Oct  8 14:21 hpet
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root             0 Oct  8 14:21 hugepages
crw------- 1 root root       10, 183 Oct  8 14:21 hwrng
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root           480 Oct  8 14:21 input
crw-r--r-- 1 root root        1,  11 Oct  8 14:21 kmsg
crw-rw-rw- 1 root kvm        10, 232 Oct  8 14:21 kvm
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root            60 Oct  8 14:21 lightnvm
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root            28 Oct  8 14:21 log -> /run/systemd/journal/dev-log
crw-rw---- 1 root disk       10, 237 Oct  8 14:21 loop-control
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root            60 Oct  8 14:21 mapper
crw-r----- 1 root kmem        1,   1 Oct  8 14:21 mem
drwxrwxrwt 2 root root            40 Oct  8 14:21 mqueue
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root            60 Oct  8 14:21 net
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root        1,   3 Oct  8 14:21 null
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root      195,   0 Oct  8 14:21 nvidia0
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root      195, 255 Oct  8 14:21 nvidiactl
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root      195, 254 Oct  8 14:21 nvidia-modeset
crw------- 1 root root       10, 144 Oct  8 14:21 nvram
crw-r----- 1 root kmem        1,   4 Oct  8 14:21 port
crw------- 1 root root      108,   0 Oct  8 14:21 ppp
crw------- 1 root root       10,   1 Oct  8 14:21 psaux
crw-rw-rw- 1 root tty         5,   2 Oct 10 11:39 ptmx
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root             0 Oct  8 14:21 pts
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root        1,   8 Oct  8 14:21 random
crw------- 1 root root       10, 242 Oct  8 14:21 rfkill
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root             4 Oct  8 14:21 rtc -> rtc0
crw------- 1 root root      249,   0 Oct  8 14:21 rtc0
brw-rw---- 1 root disk        8,   0 Oct  8 14:21 sda
brw-rw---- 1 root disk        8,   1 Oct  8 14:21 sda1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk        8,   2 Oct  8 14:21 sda2
brw-rw---- 1 root disk        8,   3 Oct  8 14:21 sda3
brw-rw---- 1 root disk        8,   4 Oct  8 14:21 sda4
brw-rw---- 1 root disk        8,  16 Oct  8 14:21 sdb
brw-rw---- 1 root disk        8,  17 Oct  8 14:21 sdb1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk        8,  18 Oct  8 14:21 sdb2
drwxrwxrwt 2 root root            40 Oct 10 11:39 shm
crw------- 1 root root       10, 231 Oct  8 14:21 snapshot
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root           400 Oct  8 14:21 snd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root            15 Oct  8 14:21 stderr -> /proc/self/fd/2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root            15 Oct  8 14:21 stdin -> /proc/self/fd/0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root            15 Oct  8 14:21 stdout -> /proc/self/fd/1
crw-rw-rw- 1 root tty         5,   0 Oct 10 11:15 tty
crw--w---- 1 root tty         4,   0 Oct  8 14:21 tty0
crw--w---- 1 root tty         4,   1 Oct  8 14:21 tty1
crw--w---- 1 root tty         4,  10 Oct  8 14:21 tty10
crw--w---- 1 root tty         4,  11 Oct  8 14:21 tty11
crw--w---- 1 root tty         4,  12 Oct  8 14:21 tty12
crw--w---- 1 root tty         4,  13 Oct  8 14:21 tty13
crw--w---- 1 root tty         4,  14 Oct  8 14:21 tty14
crw--w---- 1 root tty         4,  15 Oct  8 14:21 tty15
crw--w---- 1 root tty         4,  16 Oct  8 14:21 tty16
crw--w---- 1 root tty         4,  17 Oct  8 14:21 tty17
crw--w---- 1 root tty         4,  18 Oct  8 14:21 tty18
crw--w---- 1 root tty         4,  19 Oct  8 14:21 tty19
crw--w---- 1 root tty         4,   2 Oct  8 14:21 tty2
crw--w---- 1 root tty         4,  20 Oct  8 14:21 tty20
crw--w---- 1 root tty         4,  21 Oct  8 14:21 tty21
crw--w---- 1 root tty         4,  22 Oct  8 14:21 tty22
crw--w---- 1 root tty         4,  23 Oct  8 14:21 tty23
crw--w---- 1 root tty         4,  24 Oct  8 14:21 tty24
crw--w---- 1 root tty         4,  25 Oct  8 14:21 tty25
crw--w---- 1 root tty         4,  26 Oct  8 14:21 tty26
crw--w---- 1 root tty         4,  27 Oct  8 14:21 tty27
crw--w---- 1 root tty         4,  28 Oct  8 14:21 tty28
crw--w---- 1 root tty         4,  29 Oct  8 14:21 tty29
crw--w---- 1 root tty         4,   3 Oct  8 14:21 tty3
crw--w---- 1 root tty         4,  30 Oct  8 14:21 tty30
crw--w---- 1 root tty         4,  31 Oct  8 14:21 tty31
crw--w---- 1 root tty         4,  32 Oct  8 14:21 tty32
crw--w---- 1 root tty         4,  33 Oct  8 14:21 tty33
crw--w---- 1 root tty         4,  34 Oct  8 14:21 tty34
crw--w---- 1 root tty         4,  35 Oct  8 14:21 tty35
crw--w---- 1 root tty         4,  36 Oct  8 14:21 tty36
crw--w---- 1 root tty         4,  37 Oct  8 14:21 tty37
crw--w---- 1 root tty         4,  38 Oct  8 14:21 tty38
crw--w---- 1 root tty         4,  39 Oct  8 14:21 tty39
crw--w---- 1 root tty         4,   4 Oct  8 14:21 tty4
crw--w---- 1 root tty         4,  40 Oct  8 14:21 tty40
crw--w---- 1 root tty         4,  41 Oct  8 14:21 tty41
crw--w---- 1 root tty         4,  42 Oct  8 14:21 tty42
crw--w---- 1 root tty         4,  43 Oct  8 14:21 tty43
crw--w---- 1 root tty         4,  44 Oct  8 14:21 tty44
crw--w---- 1 root tty         4,  45 Oct  8 14:21 tty45
crw--w---- 1 root tty         4,  46 Oct  8 14:21 tty46
crw--w---- 1 root tty         4,  47 Oct  8 14:21 tty47
crw--w---- 1 root tty         4,  48 Oct  8 14:21 tty48
crw--w---- 1 root tty         4,  49 Oct  8 14:21 tty49
crw--w---- 1 root tty         4,   5 Oct  8 14:21 tty5
crw--w---- 1 root tty         4,  50 Oct  8 14:21 tty50
crw--w---- 1 root tty         4,  51 Oct  8 14:21 tty51
crw--w---- 1 root tty         4,  52 Oct  8 14:21 tty52
crw--w---- 1 root tty         4,  53 Oct  8 14:21 tty53
crw--w---- 1 root tty         4,  54 Oct  8 14:21 tty54
crw--w---- 1 root tty         4,  55 Oct  8 14:21 tty55
crw--w---- 1 root tty         4,  56 Oct  8 14:21 tty56
crw--w---- 1 root tty         4,  57 Oct  8 14:21 tty57
crw--w---- 1 root tty         4,  58 Oct  8 14:21 tty58
crw--w---- 1 root tty         4,  59 Oct  8 14:21 tty59
crw--w---- 1 root tty         4,   6 Oct  8 14:21 tty6
crw--w---- 1 root tty         4,  60 Oct  8 14:21 tty60
crw--w---- 1 root tty         4,  61 Oct  8 14:21 tty61
crw--w---- 1 root tty         4,  62 Oct  8 14:21 tty62
crw--w---- 1 root tty         4,  63 Oct  8 14:21 tty63
crw--w---- 1 root tty         4,   7 Oct  8 14:21 tty7
crw--w---- 1 root tty         4,   8 Oct  8 14:21 tty8
crw--w---- 1 root tty         4,   9 Oct  8 14:21 tty9
crw-rw---- 1 root uucp        4,  64 Oct  8 14:21 ttyS0
crw-rw---- 1 root uucp        4,  65 Oct  8 14:21 ttyS1
crw-rw---- 1 root uucp        4,  66 Oct  8 14:21 ttyS2
crw-rw---- 1 root uucp        4,  67 Oct  8 14:21 ttyS3
crw-rw---- 1 root kvm        10,  61 Oct  8 14:21 udmabuf
crw------- 1 root root       10, 239 Oct  8 14:21 uhid
crw------- 1 root root       10, 223 Oct  8 14:21 uinput
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root        1,   9 Oct  8 14:21 urandom
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root            60 Oct  8 14:21 usb
crw------- 1 root root       10, 240 Oct  8 14:21 userio
crw------- 1 root root       10,  59 Oct  8 14:21 vboxdrv
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root       10,  58 Oct  8 14:21 vboxdrvu
crw------- 1 root root       10,  57 Oct  8 14:21 vboxnetctl
drwxr-x--- 4 root vboxusers       80 Oct  8 14:21 vboxusb
crw-rw---- 1 root tty         7,   0 Oct  8 14:21 vcs
crw-rw---- 1 root tty         7,   1 Oct  8 14:21 vcs1
crw-rw---- 1 root tty         7,   2 Oct  8 14:21 vcs2
crw-rw---- 1 root tty         7,   3 Oct  8 14:21 vcs3
crw-rw---- 1 root tty         7,   4 Oct  8 14:21 vcs4
crw-rw---- 1 root tty         7,   5 Oct  8 14:21 vcs5
crw-rw---- 1 root tty         7,   6 Oct  8 14:21 vcs6
crw-rw---- 1 root tty         7,  63 Oct  9 01:59 vcs63
crw-rw---- 1 root tty         7, 128 Oct  8 14:21 vcsa
crw-rw---- 1 root tty         7, 129 Oct  8 14:21 vcsa1
crw-rw---- 1 root tty         7, 130 Oct  8 14:21 vcsa2
crw-rw---- 1 root tty         7, 131 Oct  8 14:21 vcsa3
crw-rw---- 1 root tty         7, 132 Oct  8 14:21 vcsa4
crw-rw---- 1 root tty         7, 133 Oct  8 14:21 vcsa5
crw-rw---- 1 root tty         7, 134 Oct  8 14:21 vcsa6
crw-rw---- 1 root tty         7, 191 Oct  9 01:59 vcsa63
crw-rw---- 1 root tty         7,  64 Oct  8 14:21 vcsu
crw-rw---- 1 root tty         7,  65 Oct  8 14:21 vcsu1
crw-rw---- 1 root tty         7,  66 Oct  8 14:21 vcsu2
crw-rw---- 1 root tty         7,  67 Oct  8 14:21 vcsu3
crw-rw---- 1 root tty         7,  68 Oct  8 14:21 vcsu4
crw-rw---- 1 root tty         7,  69 Oct  8 14:21 vcsu5
crw-rw---- 1 root tty         7,  70 Oct  8 14:21 vcsu6
crw-rw---- 1 root tty         7, 127 Oct  9 01:59 vcsu63
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root            60 Oct  8 14:21 vfio
crw------- 1 root root       10,  63 Oct  8 14:21 vga_arbiter
crw------- 1 root root       10, 137 Oct  8 14:21 vhci
crw------- 1 root root       10, 238 Oct  8 14:21 vhost-net
crw------- 1 root root       10, 241 Oct  8 14:21 vhost-vsock
crw------- 1 root root       10, 130 Oct  8 14:21 watchdog
crw------- 1 root root      246,   0 Oct  8 14:21 watchdog0
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root        1,   5 Oct  8 14:21 zero
```

PHP runs same user as terminal user:
`echo shell_exec("id");` returns:

```
uid=1000(alien) gid=998(wheel) groups=998(wheel),108(vboxusers),150(wireshark)
```

Running `id` in terminal returns:

```
uid=1000(alien) gid=998(wheel) groups=998(wheel),108(vboxusers),150(wireshark)
```

**Please help, why I don't see all entries in `/dev` and how to solve that?**

p.s Apache is also running as same user

Maybe it is about environment?
if I run `echo shell_exec("/bin/printenv");` it returns:

```
PWD=/home/alien/http/localhost
HOME=/home/alien
USER=alien
SHLVL=0
_=/bin/printenv
```

running `printenv` in terminal returns:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
SESSION_MANAGER=local/black:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/748,unix/black:/tmp/.ICE-unix/748
WINDOWID=71303175
QT_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTORS=DVI-I-0=1;VGA-0=1;DVI-I-1=1;HDMI-0=1;
COLORTERM=truecolor
XDG_SESSION_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session1
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups
LANGUAGE=
SHELL_SESSION_ID=2cf1621fe1f04785b31888421768dd02
DESKTOP_SESSION=/usr/share/xsessions/plasma
GTK_RC_FILES=/etc/gtk/gtkrc:/home/alien/.gtkrc:/home/alien/.config/gtkrc
XCURSOR_SIZE=24
GTK_MODULES=canberra-gtk-module
XDG_SEAT=seat0
PWD=/home/alien
XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=KDE
LOGNAME=alien
XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11
XAUTHORITY=/home/alien/.Xauthority
MOTD_SHOWN=pam
GTK2_RC_FILES=/etc/gtk-2.0/gtkrc:/home/alien/.gtkrc-2.0:/home/alien/.config/gtkrc-2.0
HOME=/home/alien
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=KDE
KONSOLE_DBUS_SERVICE=:1.689
KONSOLE_DBUS_SESSION=/Sessions/2
PROFILEHOME=
XDG_SEAT_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
KONSOLE_VERSION=200801
KDE_SESSION_UID=1000
XDG_SESSION_CLASS=user
TERM=xterm-256color
USER=alien
COLORFGBG=15;0
KDE_SESSION_VERSION=5
PAM_KWALLET5_LOGIN=/run/user/1000/kwallet5.socket
DISPLAY=:0
SHLVL=1
XDG_VTNR=1
XDG_SESSION_ID=2
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=0
XCURSOR_THEME=breeze_cursors
KDE_FULL_SESSION=true
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
KDE_APPLICATIONS_AS_SCOPE=1
MAIL=/var/spool/mail/alien
KONSOLE_DBUS_WINDOW=/Windows/1
_=/usr/bin/printenv
```

I also get different result in php if I run:

```
echo shell_exec("sudo -u alien /bin/printenv");


MAIL=/var/mail/alien
LOGNAME=alien
USER=alien
HOME=/home/alien
SHELL=/bin/bash
TERM=unknown
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
SUDO_COMMAND=/bin/printenv
SUDO_USER=alien
SUDO_UID=1000
SUDO_GID=998
```

Comment: Please provide _relevant_ details about this server, such as Linux distribution, installed software, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I've got it!
It was a default setting in `php-fpm.service` file:

```
# Sets up a new /dev namespace for the executed processes and only adds API pseudo devices
# such as /dev/null, /dev/zero or /dev/random (as well as the pseudo TTY subsystem) to it,
# but no physical devices such as /dev/sda.
PrivateDevices=true
```

So I set it to `false` and suddenly I have full access to directory items.

Took a whole day to find it out...